# Django, how to write in a different log file for each user?

Tags: python, django, logging, django-rest-framework

I read in the official [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/) how to use logging in django and it is fine. Hierarchical loggers are also cool. But what if I want to save in a different file for each user or whatever category? 
What is the best way to do it?

It would be great to have something like:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('myproject.users.' + name)
```

Is there a way to parametrize the `FileHandler` filename automatically according to the passed name?

Moreover, I would also ask:

- Are there known issues in using multiple files for logging?
- Is there a preferred path in which to save logging files in django?

Comment: What is it that you're trying to log that needs a separate log per user?..

Comment: I would like to store each time a user access a rest api so that i can later computer per user statistics. I thought to use a periodic task that read these files and store the summarized information into the db.

Comment: A deferred logging file handler for Django http://codeinthehole.com/writing/a-deferred-logging-file-handler-for-django/

Comment: I don't know the answer for your question, but I guess it does not scale that well. what if you just store the user id/ name in a field and grep the loglines? I use it all the time: `cat $LOGFILE | grep $USER_ID`

Comment: @fodma1 yes I thought about that, and maybe I'll adopt that solution, but if users want to see their own logs (lets say they want to see the last 100 queries performed with their account) I think it would be much quicker with separate files as long as the number of queries >> number of users.

Comment: @SimoV8 What if you log in JSON (One line one JSON string) and you set up a logwatcher and index it in a DB? I wouldn't serve textual files like this on a webserver.. If it's in the DB it gives you much more flexibility (imagine the case when you don't want the users to see some part of the log)